# Replacing value in excel after each iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer the cell in the current sheet to a cell in another sheet and print it out. I want the same process to repeat but offset the reference cell for the formula by one row and zero column until there is the reference cell is empty.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sheet2!R[2]C[1]"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sheet2!R[3]C[1]"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sheet2!R[4]C[1]"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
```

Comment: Is there more code? Not sure what the scope is - sounds like you just need a simple loop from the second row down to the last row. Not exactly sure what you want to be done inside the loop though. Please give more detail/code

Comment: Yeah. That exactly what I want. I just want a loop from one cell to the last, until the last cell is empty

Answer (score 0):

This?

Also, I wouldn't rely on the `ActiveCell`. Is there a specific cell you want to continuously overwrite? In the below code, I changing `A1` for each iteration so you will need to update this to the desired cell range.

---

```
Sub PrintMe()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim LR As Long
LR = ws2.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR
    ws1.Range("A1").Value = ws2.Range("A" & i).Value
    ws1.PrintOut
Next i

End Sub
```